# using batches results in errors (3D or 4D tensor expected for input, expected input to have 9 channels, but got 4 channels )

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, generator

I have this code that works fine.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# attention module for FRU
class attention_FRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_channels_down, pad='reflect'):
        super(attention_FRU, self).__init__()
        # layers to generate conditional convolution weights
        self.gen_se_weights1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels_down, num_channels_down, 1, padding_mode=pad),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True), # Dont use Softplus here
            nn.Sigmoid())

        # create conv layers
        self.conv_1 = nn.Conv2d(num_channels_down, num_channels_down, 1, padding_mode=pad)
        self.norm_1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_down, affine=False)
        self.actvn = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        # self.actvn = nn.Softplus()

    def forward(self, guide, x):
        se_weights1 = self.gen_se_weights1(guide)
        dx = self.conv_1(x)
        dx = self.norm_1(dx)
        dx = torch.mul(dx, se_weights1)
        out = self.actvn(dx)
        return out

class hs_net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ym_channel, yh_channel, num_channels_down, num_channels_up, num_channels_skip,
                 filter_size_down, filter_size_up, filter_skip_size):
        super(hs_net,self).__init__()

        self.FRU = attention_FRU(num_channels_down)
        self.up_bic = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=4, mode='bicubic')
        self.up_trans = nn.ConvTranspose2d(yh_channel,yh_channel,filter_size_down,stride=4,padding=1)

        self.guide_ms = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(ym_channel, num_channels_down, filter_size_down, padding ='same',padding_mode='reflect'),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_down),
            # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
            nn.Softplus())

        self.enc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels_down, num_channels_down, filter_size_down,padding='same', padding_mode='reflect'),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_down),
            # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
            nn.Softplus())

        self.skip = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels_down, num_channels_skip, filter_skip_size, padding ='same', padding_mode='reflect'),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_skip),
            # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
            nn.Softplus())

        self.dc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d((num_channels_skip + num_channels_up), num_channels_up, filter_size_up,padding='same',padding_mode='reflect'),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_up),
            # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
            nn.Softplus())
        self.out_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels_up, yh_channel, 1, padding_mode='reflect'),
            nn.Sigmoid())
        self.conv_hs = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(yh_channel,num_channels_down,filter_size_down, padding = 'same',padding_mode = 'reflect'))
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_down),
            # nn.Softplus())
        self.conv_bn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels_down,num_channels_down,filter_size_down, padding = 'same',padding_mode = 'reflect'),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels_down),
            # # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
            nn.Softplus())
        self.ym_channels= ym_channel
    def forward(self, inputs):
        ym = inputs[:, :self.ym_channels, :, :]
        yh = inputs[:, self.ym_channels:, :, :]
        
        ym_en0 = self.guide_ms(ym)
        ym_en1 = self.enc(ym_en0)
        ym_en2 = self.enc(ym_en1)
        ym_en3 = self.enc(ym_en2)
        ym_en4 = self.enc(ym_en3)

        ym_dc0 = self.enc(ym_en4)
        ym_dc1 = self.enc(ym_dc0)
        ym_dc2 = self.dc(torch.cat((self.skip(ym_en4), ym_dc1), dim=1))
        ym_dc3 = self.dc(torch.cat((self.skip(ym_en3), ym_dc2), dim=1))
        ym_dc4 = self.dc(torch.cat((self.skip(ym_en2), ym_dc3), dim=1))
        ym_dc5 = self.dc(torch.cat((self.skip(ym_en1), ym_dc4), dim=1))
        ym_dc6 = self.dc(torch.cat((self.skip(ym_en0), ym_dc5), dim=1))

        
        yh_6 = self.FRU(self.conv_hs(yh), ym_dc0)
        yh_7 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_6), ym_dc1)
        yh_8 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_7), ym_dc2)
        yh_9 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_8), ym_dc3)
        yh_10 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_9), ym_dc4)
        yh_11 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_10), ym_dc5)
        yh_12 = self.FRU(self.conv_bn(yh_11), ym_dc6)

       

        out = self.out_layer(yh_12)

        return out

class MyDataGenerator(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, batch_size):
          self.data = torch.squeeze(data)
          self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def __len__(self):
          return int(np.ceil(self.data.shape[0] / self.batch_size))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
          # Calculate the start and end indices of the batch
          start_idx = index * self.batch_size
          end_idx = min((index + 1) * self.batch_size, self.data.shape[0])
          # Select samples for the batch
          batch_data = self.data[start_idx:end_idx]
          return batch_data
    
    
inputs = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(1, 181, 512, 512)).to(device,dtype=torch.float)


num_iter = 1000
LR = 0.001
n_channels=172

net=hs_net(ym_channel=9, 
           yh_channel=n_channels,
           num_channels_down=16, 
           num_channels_up=16,
           num_channels_skip=16,
           filter_size_down=1,
           filter_size_up=1,
           filter_skip_size=1).to(device)

msi = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(9, 512, 512)).to(device,dtype=torch.float)
hsi = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(172, 128, 128)).to(device,dtype=torch.float)

targets=[msi,hsi]
gband=msi.shape[0]
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=LR, eps=1e-3, amsgrad=True)

def hs_loss(model,inputs,targets):
    ym = targets[0] 
    yh=targets[1] 
    
    xhat=model(inputs)
    return xhat
   
        
for it in range(num_iter):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss, out_HR = hs_loss(net, inputs, targets)
```

but when I try to use batches:

```
  train_set = MyDataGenerator(inputs, batch_size=4)
  data_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set)
    
    for it in range(num_iter):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        for batch in data_generator:
            loss, out_HR = hs_loss(net, batch, targets)
```

it gives me:

```
Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 9, 1, 1], expected input[1, 4, 512, 512] to have 9 channels, but got 4 channels instead
```

If I try :

```
train_set = MyDataGenerator(inputs, batch_size=9)
```

I receive:

```
3D or 4D (batch mode) tensor expected for input, but got: [ torch.cuda.FloatTensor{1,0,512,512} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using [`torch.data.utils.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset), please read the documentation page for more information. You don't have to worry about assembling the batch yourself, the point is for your dataset's `__getitem__` to *return a single element at a time*. It's the job of [`torch.data.utils.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) to collate the data properly depending on a batch size. Here is a demonstration following your example:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = torch.squeeze(data)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
          return self.data[index]
```

First, define dummy data (make sure the number of elements is larger than 1 of course). Then initialize the dataset and wrap it with a data loader:

```
>>> inputs = torch.rand(10, 181, 512, 512)
>>> dataloader = DataLoader(MyDataset(inputs), batch_size=4)
```

Now, you can iterate using dataloader which provides a sampler to navigate through the dataset:

```
>>> for batch in dataloader:
...     # batch has a shape of (4, 181, 512, 512)
```

Comment: Thanks! (upv!).I don't use pytorch in general, so ok it is different. I have [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087337/unsupervised-model-concatop-dimensions-of-inputs-should-match-shape0-2) problem if you think you can help, thanks!